# Using useSelect creates "minified React error"

Tags: block-editor

I'm working on a Gutenberg block that will be a dropdown menu of all posts on the site.  I used `@wordpress/create-block` (version 4.4.0) for the scaffolding.  When I try to use the `useSelect` function, it get "This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed." in addition to an error:

[image]

I'm trying to use code that was previously successful, although that code did not use the `@wordpress/create-block` scaffolding (I built everything from scratch and the `@wordpress/scripts` npm).

Here's my code:

```
 import {useSelect} from "@wordpress/data"

 export default function Edit() {
    const allCPTposts = useSelect(select => {

        return select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "post", {per_page: -1})
    })

    if(allCPTposts == undefined){
        return <p>Loading Posts...</p>
    }

    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps() }>
            { __( 'Dropdown Menu – hello from the editor!', 'dropdown' ) }
        </p>
    );
}
```

I'm not able to even work on the JSX for the actual dropdown menu because of this error.

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error reads "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render." - so I'd assume the `useBlockProps()` is the culprit here. If you move that above the conditional return, does it work again?

Comment: @kero That absolutely fixed it!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Unrelated to your error, you've tried to use `per_page: -1` which is not possible, and if it were possible would be dangerous. The REST API caps requests at 100 posts for performance and scaling reasons. Arguably you should also be doing this in server side queries but there is no cap there, so while you can try to use `-1`, you will never get all posts unless there are less than 100. The API returns 10 per page by default

Comment: @kero please post your answer as an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [URL given with the error message](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=310), you will see the full text as:

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

Inspecting the code, I see two uses of hooks:

```
export default function Edit() {
    const allCPTposts = useSelect(select => {
//                      ^ first hook use 
        return select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "post", {per_page: -1})
    })

    if(allCPTposts == undefined){
        return <p>Loading Posts...</p>
    }

    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps() }>
{/*             ^ second hook use */}
            { __( 'Dropdown Menu – hello from the editor!', 'dropdown' ) }
        </p>
    );
}
```

So it seems sometimes just `useSelect()` and sometimes both `useSelect()` and `useBlockProps()` are called.

Seeing that there is an early return before the second hook use, this is most likely the issue here. Just move the `useBlockProps()` call above the early return and the component will always call the same amount of hooks for each render.